# How can I position the element generated by XMLTEXT in a FOR XML query?

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-server-2017, xml

I'm trying to use `FOR XML` to simulate an OData feed. One of the requirements I have is that somewhere I need an XML element which is constant for all records; I was planning to use the [XMLTEXT directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/example-specifying-the-xmltext-directive?view=sql-server-2017) for this.

My XML needs to look like this; for every record in the database,

```xml
<entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <test type="dummy" />
    <!-- some more nested elements -->
</entry>
```

When I use the following query, the `<test>` element appears **before** the `<id>` element, even though the declaration appears *after* it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1), (2);

SELECT
  1    AS Tag,
  NULL AS Parent,
  id   AS [entry!1!id!ELEMENT],
  '<test type="dummy" />'
       AS [entry!1!test!XMLTEXT]
  -- other columns
  FROM #temp
  FOR XML EXPLICIT;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

This gives the following results ([fiddle](https://rextester.com/JFKJ52838)):

```xml
<entry>
    <test type="dummy"/>
    <id>1</id>
</entry>
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a limitation of XMLTEXT? A workaround might be to treat it as a regular nested element, but would that work even though I have more nested elements further down in the `<entry>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more fiddling, I found out that there is an XML directive which does the job (if I omit the attribute name, `test`):

```
SELECT
  1    AS Tag,
  NULL AS Parent,
  id   AS [entry!1!id!ELEMENT],
  '<test type="dummy" />'
       AS [entry!1!!XML]
  FROM #temp
  FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

This produces the results I want:

```xml
<entry><id>1</id><test type="dummy" /></entry>
```

([demo](https://rextester.com/MPUMA7860))

This directive is mentioned briefly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017) but I couldn't find more documentation or any examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason does not need `for xml explicit` you could use `for xml path` instead which I for one think is a bit easier to handle.

You could cast the string literal to XML

```
select T.id,
       cast('<test type="dummy" />' as xml)
from #temp as T
for xml path('entry');
```

Or you could set it up as a value

```
select T.id,
       'dummy' as [test/@type]
from #temp as T
for xml path('entry');
```